# How to get sudo in a vanilla debian buster on openshift?

Tags: kubernetes, debian, openshift, kubectl, sudo

I'm trying to get a debian instance running on openshift and install some software with apt-get. Unfortunately sudo is not working and I don't know the root password.

```
$ kubectl run my-shell --rm -i --tty --image debian:buster -- bash
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
1002410000@my-shell:/$ sudo apt-get install wget
bash: sudo: command not found
1002410000@my-shell:/$ su -
Password:
1002410000@my-shell:/$ exit
exit
Session ended, resume using 'kubectl attach my-shell -c my-shell -i -t' command when the pod is running
pod "my-shell" deleted
```

So how can I make `sudo` working?

Comment: You should be building a custom image with the tools you need rather than trying to install packages into the running container. If you treat your running containers as "read-only", particularly when running in an orchestration environment like OpenShift, you'll find things much easier.

Comment: I'm not after a clean set-up. I only need a linux instance for some experiments.:Fire it up, install something, work with it for some minutes and then throw it away.

Comment: Instead of using `kubectl run`, you can create a Pod via a YAML manifest and configure it to run as `root`. You will probably need to configure the necessary RBAC in OpenShift to permit your container to run as `root`.

Answer (score 0):

As an example:

Give the right to run as any user to the`default` `serviceaccount` in your namespace:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default
```

Create this deployment:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: debian-root-volume
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: debian-root-volume
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: debian-root-volume
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0

      containers:
        - name: debian-root-volume
          image: debian:latest
          command:
            - sleep
          args:
            - "14400"
```

Connect to the pod via the console (tab "terminal" on the pod) or via the cli

```
oc rsh <pod-name>
```

and perform any action (as root, no need for`sudo`) in your debian pod